# Laravel SQLite Default Value to a field

Tags: laravel, sqlite, phpunit, migration

Okay, I've got this problem:

I'm setting a boolean property with a default value in my migrations:

```
$table->boolean('is_public')->default(1);
```

It's working perfectly fine on my initial database, MySQL. I migrated the db and inserted manually, it gets inserted as true.

Problem is, though, when I run my tests that are configured with the `sqlite` in memory database, the default value doesn't get added. So this assert:

```
$this->assertEquals($league->is_public, 1);
```

...fails when it shouldn't.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm missing? Do I have to add something more so that the default value gets added to the database or this some kind of `sqlite` issue?

Comment: And what does `dd($league->is_public)` show?

Comment: It shows `null` in my tests;

Comment: And what does `dd($league)` show?

Comment: It shows the created league. The League gets created with a name and other properties that are required and don't have a default value.

Comment: So, it shows `League` object where `is_public` is `null`? Please show how exactly you're creating the object in the test.

Answer (score 0):

Change your migration to this.

```
$table->boolean('is_public',true);
```

Comment: `boolean()` method doesn't have the second parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure it doesn't but if it doesnt just change '1' to 'true' and it should work